# python: How to determined if a value is contained in a certain column of 2D list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, list, multidimensional-array

Each index needs to appear only once. So I want to check whether a value of `2` exists already in the second column.

```
my_list = [[0, 0], 
           [1, 3], 
           [2, 5], 
           [3, 4]]
```

It should return `False` in this case if I check for "2".

Comment: what do you mean by *2nd rank*? The `[1, 3]` row or the `[0, 3, 5, 4]` column?

Comment: `any((y==2 for _, y in my_list))`

Comment: yes it is (0, 3, 5, 4)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing I would do is isolate the second elements:

```
seconds = [x for (y,x) in my_list ]
```

then I would check if `2` exists in this list with `2 in seconds` or in a single step:

```
>>> 2 in [x for (y,x) in my_list ]
False
>>> 3 in [x for (y,x) in my_list ]
True
>>>
```

Finally, from @Faibbus comment, in python if you are not interested in a value (you can ignore it) we tend to use `_` so the above becomes:

```
2 in [x for (_,x) in my_list ]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you mean the second rank is the second index then,

```
my_list = [[0, 0], [1, 3], [2, 5], [3, 4]]

for index in range(len(my_list)):
    if my_list[index][1] == 2:
       print("True")
    else:
       print("False")
```

Comment: @joonho Park: Is this what you are expecting ?

Comment: This is a kind of result which I expected. But surely, I am looking for a shorter way.